# JQuery select text next to an input checkbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using JQuery, is there a simple way to select the text immediately after a checkbox?

```
<li>bleh..</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbx1" value="10" />&nbsp;Very important text.
</li>
<li>bleh..</li>
```

I want to use jquery to select that "Very important text." minus `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Better solution might be to wrap the text in a `label` element:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbx1" value="10" />
    <label for="cbx1">Very important text.</label>
</li>
```

You can then get the text like so:

```
var text = $('label[for="cbx1"]').text();
```

This also improves the semantics of your document.

Comment: Thanks.. I like the fact the checkbox is toggled when I click on the text, just the way we are accustomed to in Windows.

Answer (score 9):

To do what you said:

```
var text = $('#cbx1').parent().text();
```

You might need to trim it though, not sure about the `&nbsp;`:

```
var text = $.trim($('#cbx1').parent().text());
```

Comment: Ah so .text() will actually get the text and ignores the html elements (the checkbox)? Now I am clear the differences between .text() and .html()